# How to compare two columns in Excel (from different sheets) and copy values from a corresponding column if the first two columns match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare column a in Sheet 1 with column a in Sheet 2, then copy corresponding values in column b from sheet 1 to column b in Sheet 2 (where the column a values match). I've been trying to read up on how to do this, but I'm not sure if I should be trying to create a macro, or if there's a simpler way to do this, maybe VLOOKUP or MATCH? I'm really not familiar with how these functions work though.

Also, if it makes a difference, there will be repeated values in column b of Sheet 2.

Sheet 1

```
12AT8001    1
12AT8002    2
12AT8003    3
12AT8004    4
12AT8005    5
12AT8006    6
```

Sheet 2

```
12AT8001
12AT8001
12AT8001
12AT8001
12AT8001
12AT8002
12AT8002
12AT8002
12AT8002
12AT8002
12AT8003
12AT8003
12AT8003
12AT8003
12AT8003
```

Answer (score 5):

`Vlookup` is good if the reference values (column A, sheet 1) are in ascending order.  Another option is Index and Match, which can be used no matter the order (As long as the values in column a, sheet 1 are unique)

This is what you would put in column B on sheet 2

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:B$6,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A$1:A$6),2)
```

Setting `Sheet1!A$1:B$6` and `Sheet1!A$1:A$6` as named ranges makes it a little more user friendly.

Comment: When I used that formula on the subset of data (that I used as an example in the question) it worked. However, when I tried it on the full set of data (600 rows for sheet1 and 2994 rows for sheet2) it gave me the #N/A error. I updated the formula to read: =INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:B$600,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A$1:A$600),2).

Comment: Then I tried with the full 600 rows on sheet1, but kept it to the same test subset for sheet2 that I used in the example. Using the same =INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:B$600,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A$1:A$600),2) formula, it returned a seemingly arbitrary number of 276 for all rows.

Comment: Perhaps its not working becasue the id's in the full set of data for sheet2 is not in the same order as sheet1 (like they were in the example)? All those id's are mixed up in the full set . . . which is why I need something faster than matching them up by hand. All the values in column A of sheet1 are unique by the way.

Any ideas as to why it won't work on the full set, or have somehting else to try?

Comment: VLOOKUP should work if the values on sheet 1 are in numerical order

Comment: I just tried it with 600 and 3000 values respectively (and the 3000 not in order) and it seems to work.  are you getting the #n/a error on all cells? set the match type to 0. Match(a1,sheet1!a$1:a$600,0) and see if that yields better results.

Comment: I just copied that formula down my entire data set and noticed that the #N/A error was given on the first 85 rows, then it returned "150" for the next 170 rows. (For the first 5 rows the pairing was correct.) Then for the next 55 rows, it worked as its supposed to matching up the numbers with their id's. Then it returned "228" for the next 270 rows. (Again here the first 5 pairing are correct.) The next 30 rows were matched correctly, then the next 320 returned "240". The craziness continues to the end. I also tried the formula setting the match type to zero, with the same results.

Comment: I'm completely baffled. :/ I also tried setting the match type to zero and got the same results. As for VLOOKUP, the values on sheet1 column A are not in any kind of order. Sheet1 column two is numerical order though.

Comment: I just tried the VLOOKUP even though the id's on sheet1 were not in numerical order and it worked! Here's the formula: =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A$1:B$600,2,FALSE)

Thank you MechEng and deusxmach1na for the suggestions, they got me thinking about the problem in different ways, which eventually led to my discovery. I really appreciate it!

Comment: there is no such thing as "numerical order" either for VLOOKUP nor INDEX(MATCH()) - VLOOKUP has argument **range_lookup** and MATCH has **match_type** that should both be set to 0 (=FALSE) for exact match in your case (and it can be set to 1 (=TRUE) to match the non-exact match if your values are sorted in ascending order - strings as well as numbers) - just read the built-in explanation of the functions in Excel or see http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/excel-vlookup-index-match.php

Answer (score 3):

As kmcamara discovered, this is exactly the kind of problem that VLOOKUP is intended to solve, and using vlookup is arguably the simplest of the alternative ways to get the job done.

In addition to the three parameters for lookup_value, table_range to be searched, and the  column_index for return values, VLOOKUP takes an optional fourth argument that the Excel documentation calls the "range_lookup".

Expanding on deathApril's explanation, if this argument is set to TRUE (or 1) or omitted, the table range must be  sorted in ascending order of the values in the first column of the range for the function to return what would typically be understood to be the "correct" value. Under this default behavior, the function will return a value based upon an exact match, if one is found, or an approximate match if an exact match is not found.

If the match is approximate, the value that is returned by the function will be based on the next largest value that is less than the lookup_value. For example, if "12AT8003" were missing from the table in Sheet 1, the lookup formulas for that value in Sheet 2 would return '2', since "12AT8002" is the largest value in the lookup column of the table range that is less than "12AT8003". (VLOOKUP's default behavior makes perfect sense if, for example, the goal is to look up rates in a tax table.)

However, if the fourth argument is set to FALSE (or 0), VLOOKUP returns a looked-up value only if there is an exact match, and an error value of #N/A if there is not. It is now the usual practice to wrap an exact VLOOKUP in an IFERROR function in order to catch the no-match gracefully. Prior to the introduction of IFERROR, no matches were checked with an IF function using the VLOOKUP formula once to check whether there was a match, and once to return the actual match value.

Though initially harder to master, deusxmach1na's proposed solution is a variation on a powerful set of alternatives to VLOOKUP that can be used to return values for a column or list to the *left* of the lookup column, expanded to handle cases where an exact match on more than one criterion is needed, or modified to incorporate OR as well as AND match conditions among multiple criteria.

Repeating kcamara's chosen solution, the VLOOKUP formula for this problem would be:

```
   =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A$1:B$600,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a truth table and use SUMPRODUCT to get the values.  Copy this into cell B1 on Sheet2 and copy down as far as you need:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--($A1 = Sheet1!$A:$A), Sheet1!$B:$B)`
the part that creates the truth table is: 
 `--($A1 = Sheet1!$A:$A)`
This returns an array of 0's and 1's.  1 when the values match and a 0 when they don't.  Then the comma after that will basically do what I call "funny" matrix multiplication and will return the result.  I may have misunderstood your question though, are there duplicate values in Column A of Sheet1?

Comment: I'm not following your solution :( but no there are not duplicates in column A of Sheet1.

Comment: Try to just copy and paste the first formula I gave you into cell B1 on Sheet2 and fill down as far as you need.  Assuming your worksheets are setup how you mentioned in your post it should give the correct value.  It's basically multiplying 1 * the value in column B of Sheet 1 whenever column A of Sheet 1 matches the value in Column A of Sheet 2.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
sheet 2 a1 =vlookup(sheet2a1,sheet1$a$1:$b$6,2)
```

Then drag it down.

It should work.