# How to search columns in two workbooks for matching value and write a value from different column from same matching row to one of workbooks?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to to be able to open two Excel workbooks and compare a column from each that may have matching values.  Upon discovering a matching value, I would like to grab another value from the same row in workbook 1 and write it to the same matching value row in workbook 2.

For my output file, I am simply trying to add one column of data that will match up where the values matched in the other columns I am comparing between the two workbooks.

In the example below, I would like to compare Column A between the two workbooks.  Upon finding a matching value, I would like to write the value in the same row from column C in workbook 1 to Column C in Workbook 2.

```
Input workbook 1:
A      B    C
dog    1    red
cat    2    green
bird   3    blue

Input workbook 2:
A      B       C     D       E
pig    house         stuff   stuff
cat    car           stuff   stuff
horse  train         stuff   stuff

Output Workbook 2
A       B      C       D       E
pig     house          stuff  stuff
cat     car    green   stuff  stuff
horse   trian          stuff  stuff
```

I have tried many iterations of code with openpyxl and pandas, and have not had any success.  I feel like I was closest using merge, join, concat in pandas, but the values never ended up printing anywhere that made sense.

For example, things like this ended up copying data from one workbook to the other, but it didn't match up anywhere it was supposed to.

```
df2 = df1.merge(df2, 'A', 'C')
df2 = pd.merge(df2,df1, on=['A'], how='left')
df2 = pd.concat([df1.set_index('A') for d in [df1, df2]], axis=1).reset_index()
```

If it helps, my actual data has several hundred rows in each workbook.  There are only two columns that actually match by header name.  One is the column I am comparing, and the other is the data I am trying to write from one workbook to other.

I am open to using any method that can easily compare two excel workbooks and write data from one to other based on matching values in specified columns.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use Python for this? You could do this with an Excel formula pretty easily (Vlookup, Index/Match, etc.)

Comment: I guess I didn't even consider this.  I will need to look into this next.  Thaks for the suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two columns in Excel (from different sheets) and copy values from a corresponding column if the first two columns match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193978/how-to-compare-two-columns-in-excel-from-different-sheets-and-copy-values-from)